# How to get card number and expiration date from debit/credit card?

Tags: android, credit-card, apdu

I have a card reader to read cards with chip for android (it connects via usb). I can connect to card reader and power on card itself. But I cannot understand reponse when I send APDU command. Here is my code.

```
String command = "00A404000E315041592E5359532E4444463031";
byte[] commandByte = apdu.s2ba(command);
byte[] prevByte = new byte[30];
int[] prevLen = new int[1];
prevLen[0] = 30;
int status = reader.SCardTransmit(commandByte, commandByte.length, prevByte, prevLen);
Log.i("ab", Integer.toString(status)+"----"+apdu.ba2s(prevByte));
```

I am getting response

```
09-02 23:30:19.648  25744-25744/com.nnadir.scanertest4 I/ab﹕ 0----30: 611700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

but it must be  something like this

```
6F 1A 84 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 08 88 01 01 5F 2D 02 65 6E
```

I am following [this](http://blog.saush.com/2006/09/08/getting-information-from-an-emv-chip-card/) guide

Answer (score 0):

I found that 6117 in response after apdu command shows that command was succesfull (61) and 17 bytes response available. So we need to send second apdu command to get that response

00C0000017 - here 17 is number of bytes we expect and now in response we get information we needed.